# @internal user not working for Customer Community User

Tags: chatter, user, customer-community, chatter-feed, mentions

When a community user tries to do @mention internal user on record feed then internal user does not shows up where as when a internal user can  @mention Community user then it works.

Also tried by adding Sharing rule on User

```
Users who are members of All Internal Users
Share with  All Customer Portal Users
User Access = Read/Write
```

where as Community user can @mention system admin user.
Note: System Admin Profile is added a member of Customer Community under Community Settings.

Comment: Are you doing this just to add bounty to yourself?

Comment: @Oleksiy After adding bounty to my question then I got the answer to my question.I am not sure how to remove this bounty.

Comment: I think in this case you are fine ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added internal user profile as member of community and that allowed internal and external users to collaborate on a record feed.

Comment: even I add the system admin profile as a member of the community it not showing the system admin name.